# Adding TFS Group, AD groups and setting permissions in powershell

Tags: tfs, powershell-2.0, tfs-sdk

I am trying to automate the process of creating the TFS groups and adding the AD groups to it and permissions. I was able to create the tfs group and add the AD groups to it. Now I need to do the same at the project level and at different branch levels like dev, main, hotfix, etc. (when you go to tfs right click on the project->advanced->security). I am using the commands

```
iex "& $tfSecurityCmd /gcg `"Group name`" `"Group Desc`" /collection:`"$adressTFS1`" | /server:`"?`"" 

#iex "& $tfSecurityCmd /gc `"vstfs:///Classification/TeamProject/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`" `"Group Name`" `"Group Desc`" /collection:?"
```

Neither works.  I cant figure out the server URL and in the second case the collection URL, as when I right click and do properties, it does not gives me an URL.

Answer (score 0):

ok I got it working now, just needed to add some escape charaters here and there